# How to set Merge output as Select Input in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, merge, select

I'm using ModelBuilder. I tried to take the Output from the Merge tool as Input to the Select tool. But it doesn't work.
I'm trying to Merge 90 Shapefile lines into one. Then "Select" some features (with an expression) from the WHOLE one to do more things.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select tool only work with layer. So after the output of the merge tool, insert a "Make feature layer" (data management) and them connect the output of this tool to the select tool.

Comment: Sorry @jeb but I can't connect The Merge's output as MakeFeatureLayer's Input

Comment: What are you merging? Shouldn't there be two featureclasses or shapefiles as input for the merge. What do you see when you validate your model? (press the check mark, second icon from the right).

Comment: The Select Layer By Attribute tool needs a layer made first, but the Select tool (which is being used here) works fine on a feature class so Make Feature Layer is not needed.

Comment: @PolyGeo, you're right! My mistake, so it was HDR that has the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mates, I didn't know that I need to fill the Input of the Merge tool. Here is the pict:

Thanks!

[image]